# Get values from dynamic string array in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

In angular material form, I have a field with mat-option which contains list of options(i.e., a, b, c, d, e). When user selects/unselects one particular option(i.e., c), I need to do some manipulation. 
But I am getting undefined error, even if I select an option 'c' without selecting any other option.

I can understand that it is due to the index value[2] that I have used. I am not sure on how to identify if the user selects option 'C' or not Since it's index value may increase or decrease dynamically based on user selection.

Response array may look like:

```
value = {'d','c'} or value = {'c','b','a'} or value = {}

if(value[2] === 'c') {
   console.log('c');
 }
```

Can someone help me to write typescript code?

Comment: {'d','c'} is not an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe there's a missing thing in your code. Since you told us that you use `mat-option`, I tried to create sample code using that.

component.html

```html
<h4>mat select</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Choose option</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="optionControl" required (valueChange)="onChange($event)">
    <mat-option>--</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
      {{option}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>  
</mat-form-field>

<div>
  <p>Selected value</p>
  {{ optionControl.value }}
</div>
```

component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: 'app-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['app-example.css'],
})
export class AppExampleComponent {
  optionControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);  
  options = ['a', 'b', 'c']; // this is static but should be dynamic for your case

  onChange(value: string) { // value will be selected option
    if (value === 'c') {
      console.log('c');
    }
  }
}
```

Take a look at the action on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/61569309-angular-material-select)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `value = {'d','c'} or value = {'c','b','a'} or value = {}` is something legit JavaScript/TypeScript syntax for objects. Unless you were referring to something like `{c: 'c'}`

In that case it's an object and you need either `Object.keys()` or `Object.values()` to convert it to an array first.

```js
const value = {
  c: 'c',
  b: 'b',
  a: 'a'
};

if(Object.values(value).includes('c')) {
  console.log('c');
} else {
  console.log('NO c'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say user can select multiple options. You need to subscribe to selection change, or call a method from `HTML` whenever change happens. For example all selected values are stored in `values` variable. How are selected values stored in `values` depends on the way you detect change. After every selection change split that variable to an array like this:

```
let valuesArray = values.toString().split(',');
```

Then check every array element:

```
valuesArray.forEach(v => { if (v === 'c') { console.log('c'); } });
```